# Create a dictionary of whitespaces based on list of whitespace-sizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, whitespace

I have a list that looks like:

```
sizes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now I want to create a dictionary whose values are the list values, whereas keys are whitespaces of sizes that are equal to values. The expected dictionary should look like this:

```
dic[' ']=1
dic['  ']=2
dic['   ']=3
dic['    ']=4
dic['     ']=5
dic['      ']=6
```

TIA

Comment: Can't you just use `len('    ')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple dict-comprehension:

```
>>> sizes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> {' '*k:k for k in sizes}
{' ': 1, '  ': 2, '   ': 3, '    ': 4, '     ': 5, '      ': 6}
```

Comment: Or a fun(ctional) way: `from operator import mul; dict(zip(map(mul, ' '*len(sizes), sizes), sizes))`